# Same regex behaves differently on grepl versus stri_detect_regex

Tags: r, stringi

**edit** *I encounter this on R version 3.6.1, appearently in newer versions this issue does not exist and the functions do behave similar.*

Consider this vector, where the first element is in the Latin-1 Supplement unicode block, the second element is in the Latin Extended Additional unicode block, and element 3-7 are in the Latin Extended D unicode block (Same I see for the Latin Extended E unicode block). The regular expression used is `^[\\p{L} ]+$` which is supposed to match a string with any kind of letter from any language. I see that `grepl` and `stri_detect_regex` interpret `p{L}` differently.

```
v <- c("é", "Ḃ", "Ꞵ", "ꞵ", "Ꞷ", "ꞷ","keepme", "remove$me", "remove.me")

v[grepl("^[\\p{L} ]+$", v, perl = T)]
# [1] "é"      "Ḃ"      "keepme"

v[stri_detect_regex(v, "^[\\p{L} ]+$")]
# [1] "é"      "Ḃ"      "\ua7b4" "\ua7b5" "\ua7b6" "\ua7b7" "keepme"
```

Is there any documentation on why they behave different on this expression?

Comment: The result is not reproducible on R 4.1.2, windows. Both return the second result.

Comment: @Oliver, thanks. I work on a pretty old setup here. R version 3.6.1

Comment: Then I can only suggest updating the version of R. The newest version is R 4.2.1 realeased June this year, while 3.6.1 was released back in July 2019.

Comment: On R 4.2.1 on Windows, `v[stringi::stri_detect_regex(v, "^[\\p{L} ]+$")]` returns `"é"      "Ḃ"      "Ꞵ"      "ꞵ"      "Ꞷ"      "ꞷ"      "keepme"` for me

Comment: @bretauv, that is the same as mine, just differing in displaying the unicode in the console versus de actual characters. The result is the same. I think Oliver made a good point that the gsub does behave the same in the more modern version of R, while I use a pretty ancient version.

Comment: So you specifically want to know why this didn't work in R 3.6.1 even though it's fine in newer versions? Is this for historical purposes?

Comment: @MrFlick no of course not, by asking the question and getting the reply that it works the same in recent versions my question is basically answered.

Comment: Ok. I was just confused by your edit. If you have a satisfactory answer, you should post it below as an answer rather than edit the original question so it's clear the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens on older R versions, R version 3.6.1 base grepl does not recognize all unicode blocks using regex `p{L}`, however as @Oliver commented, it does as expected in later versions of R as he tested in R 4.2.1. For me the question is answered. Thanks!